# How does one change the machine name of a Feature?

Tags: 6, features

I have created a feature with a typo in the machine name. I've tried just search/replacing instances of the misspelling with the proper spelling in all files within the feature's directory, but when I do that it disappears from the list of available features entirely. (Yes, I `drush cc all`'d.)

How can I change the machine-readable name of this feature?

Using Drupal 6, btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this procedure to rename a Feature module:

- `drush pm-disable old_feature_name`
- `drush pm-uninstall old_feature_name`
- rename the Feature module folder
- rename the `.info` file
- rename the `.module` file
- rename any hook prefixes
- `drush pm-enable new_feature_name`

Comment: I also renamed all the hook names just to be safe, and apparently I missed one. Does the above work properly when the feature is enabled?

Comment: After renaming, the module will appear disabled, since the `system` table will still indicate that the module's old name is enabled.  I'd recommend, before renaming, `drush dis` and `drush pm-uninstall`, then rename, then `drush en` with the new module name.  (I just updated my answer with the full procedure.)